# Создание журнала событий в CRUD-приложение реализованного с помощью WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server, ado.net

Доброго времени суток!
Есть стандартное CRUD-приложение, реализованное с помощью WinForms. Хотелось бы вести историю действий, т.е когда была изменена та или иная строка в таблице или когда она была удалена/добавлена. Отсюда вопрос, как лучше реализовать данный функционал?

Comment: Вы хотите протоколировать изменения данных в БД в таблицах этой БД, или в лога файле (это не одно и то же!)?

Comment: @lospejos, мне без разницы, можно и в лог можно и с помощью триггеров. Но сейчас я склоняюсь в сторону триггеров. Я же написал: "хотелось бы вести историю". Возможно я не совсем верно присвоил название теме...

Comment: Если бы я создавал приложение, и у меня была возможность по ресурсам, я бы логировал в каждом из элементов системы: протоколирование  логики (т.н. Business Logic Layer) я бы делал в лог файлах на серверах приложений, а изменения данных (Database Layer) - в специальных таблицах в БД. Потому что никогда не знаешь, что может понадобиться при разборе полетов.

Comment: @lospejos, просто если у меня будет таблица в БД с действиями пользователей, то я легко смогу вывести данные в любой другой файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону триггеров. Вы можете написать их к каждой таблице, которую необходимо отслеживать и прописать в них функциональность, которая будет делать записи, к примеру, в другую таблицу. На уровне БД это самый лучший вариант, как я считаю.

Возможно вам этот вариант подойдёт больше, чем создание `log` файла.

Comment: Ваш совет мне очень помог, спасибо!